# Forms created using workflow 'Email notification'

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

I just tried to create a form and associate workflow 'Email notification'.Do i need to specify email address for this workflow?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the mail configuration in the forms-flow-bpm (Camunda) and add appropriate mail server and email settings. And deploy it again to get the email sending part working. Please check the readme link here to know more details.
https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/tree/master/forms-flow-bpm#mail-configuration

Comment: Thanks @crystalthinker i will check and let u know